# python - reference method of object defined in main

Tags: python, object, methods, program-entry-point

In python 3.4.2 is there a way to call, from any class, a method of an object that was defined in main() ?

I am not very skilled in OOP so perhaps my understanding is wrong?  Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Below is pseudo-code; the overall goal is, in PyQt, to be able to call a method of the main window object, from inside a method of an object of any arbitrary other class.

```
class A(object):
  myVar=0
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def doit():
    print(self.myVar)

class B(object):
  def __init__(self):
    A.doit()  # uses the class variable, should print '0'
    a1.doit() # uses the object variable, should print '1'

def main():
  a1=A()
  a1.myVar=1
  b1=B()
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to KronoS for the response.  After looking at that and some more trial and error, here's an example I came up with of calling a method of an ancestor object (even if the classes have no inheritance relationship):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        b1=B(self)
    def do_stuff(self):
        print("Stuff is done")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent # needed so children of this object can reference this object's parent
        c1=C(self)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        parent.parent.do_stuff()
        # or actually make parent an object of this instance;
        #  necessary if children of this object will reference this object's parent:
        #self.parent=parent
        #self.parent.parent.do_stuff()

def main():
    a1=A()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However I'm still fairly new to this, so, let me know if there's a better way, or, if there's some reason why this whole concept should be unnecessary or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some annotations to your current code.  HOWEVER, the simple answer to your question is that you cannot reference another class without passing in an instance of that class:

```
class A(object):
    myVar=0
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def doit(self):  # <--- Missing 'self' here
        print("A.doit(): {}".format(self.myVar))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, other):

        #A.doit()       # This will not work.  It's not a class function now that we've added 'self'
        print("B.__init__: {}".format(A.myVar))
        other.doit()    # other is the passed in object


def main():
    a1=A()
    a1.myVar=1
    b1=B(a1)
    print("main: {}".format(A.myVar))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Out
# B.__init__: 0
# A.doit(): 1
# main: 0
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick answer - will just wait a while before accepting to see if anyone has found a different way.  This sounds like a quick straightforward answer to a self-contained question; if needed I'll open up a separate question on the PyQt scenario and will link to it from here.

Comment: also, to clarify, super() isn't relevant here, because using super() to form chained calls only has meaning if the classes are inherited all the way along that chain, right?  These classes have no inheritance relationship as you point out.

Comment: @TomGrundy that is correct.  If you want inheritance then you would use `super()`.